# How to take the sum of groups of cells from one column based on a matching criteria in another column?

Tags: r, dataset

I have data that looks like this.

```
    Weight     Zip
    23         88762
    45.3       34957
    37.6       87293
    212.45     34957
    58.3       87293
    92.45      88762
```

I am trying to sum the weights that correspond to the same zip code and add the result to a new column:

```
    TotalWeight
    115.45
    257.75
    95.9
    257.75 
    95.9 
    115.45
```

I thought about doing something like this but I figure there must be something more efficient.  Thanks!

```
weight <- c(23, 45.3, 37.6, 212.45, 58.3, 92.45)
zip <- c(88762L, 34957L, 87293L, 34957L, 87293L, 88762L)

function(){
zippop<-data.frame()
for (i in unique(zip)){
zippop<-rbind(zippop, c(i,sum(weight[which(zip==i)])))}
return (zippop)
}
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. That is, rather than only showing your data, make the start of your code create it, e.g. like so: `weight <- c(23, 45.3, 37.6, 212.45, 58.3, 92.45)` and (assuming you want `zip` as integer) `zip <- c(88762L, 34957L, 87293L, 34957L, 87293L, 88762L)`

Comment: I took the liberty of adding those lines for you, but your function is not immediately executable as it stands either so you should still edit your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ave()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html) works here:

```
df <- data.frame(Weight=c(23,45.3,37.6,212.45,58.3,92.45),Zip=c(88762,34957,87293,34957,87293,88762));
df$TotalWeight <- ave(df$Weight,df$Zip,FUN=sum);
df;
##   Weight   Zip TotalWeight
## 1  23.00 88762      115.45
## 2  45.30 34957      257.75
## 3  37.60 87293       95.90
## 4 212.45 34957      257.75
## 5  58.30 87293       95.90
## 6  92.45 88762      115.45
```

Comment: Just what I needed.  Thanks so much!

Comment: tapply (with the sum function) would also work